# ubuntu 22.04 rm64 starting kodi freezes monitor

Tags: 22.04, freeze, kodi, arm64

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 arm64 on a rpi4 (4Gb, ssd 480Gb) in order to run tvheadend and kodi. tvheadend installs and runs (I had to make it myself, the snap version is very old) but as soon as I start kodi I get a blank screen and the system freezes. I rebooted (powered off/on) and started kodi thus:

```
$tail -f /var/log/syslog | tee tee.log
then clicked the kodi icon. I got:
Aug  9 10:42:55 rpi4 systemd[1068]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug  9 10:42:58 rpi4 kodi.desktop[6784]: libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
Aug  9 10:42:58 rpi4 kodi.desktop[6784]: libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
```

Any ideas?
Regards, Brian.

Comment: Too late I'm afraid, I have just rebuilt the ssd card and will start all over again.From memory the error changed with another line which said "can not find vc4_drv_video.so". I'll keep you posted.Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: Hi, I have rebuilt my ssd card and have got ubuntu up and running. after apt update and apt upgrade I installed kodi apt install kodi.A this point kodi would run and I could use it. I then installed tvheadend, ./configure, make, make install, and a lot of needed libs. Now kodi freeze again. I guess one of the new libs is breaking something.  Tvh config and make asked for these. Any idea where I go from here? I can send exactly what I installed if required. Thanks and Cheers, Brian.

Comment: Added: build-essential git pkg-config libssl-dev bzip2 wget  libavahi-client-dev zlib1g-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libavresample cmake libdvbcsa-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev liburiparser-dev libva-dev libavahi-client-dev. Cheers, Brian.

Comment: I rebuilt the ssd card again, installed kodi and it ran. I then repeatedly installed each required lib and tested kodi after each, again okay. I did not install any picked out with tvh ./configure, namely libpcre3 libpcre3-dev and libva-dev. Ran tvh ./configure, make and make install and now everything is working so it must be one of these and libva looks the favourite. Cheers, Brian.

Comment: Hi, Yesterday I thought I had it cracked - today I booted the system clicked on kodi and voila blank screen. I will now answer your original questions:printenv|grep -i libva returns nothing and I can't find anything like vdpau using lsmod or less /proc/module|grep vdpau. I do have vdpau-drivers-all installed. I hope this helps. Cheers, Brian.